# How can I debug Windows Phone 8 App on Remote Server?

Tags: windows-phone, remote-debugging

Our Projects(Code/Design,etc) in remote server,They have develop windows phone scenario,such as : visual studio 2012/2013,windows phone sdk installed etc..
i know debug app must be in vs2012/2013,
but,if i want to debug app on remote server and how can connect device ?

ps:
1、Use the same network.
2、All code in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmaticaly:

Microsoft has managed APIs that allow you to install and run XAPs on either hardware device or simulator. They are implemented in 3 DLLs: Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll, Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.Interface.dll and Microsoft.Smartdevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity.dll - you should be able to google usage examples.

Unfortunately, there's no APIs for remote debugging.

If you want to do it manually:

You can use remote desktop + RemoteFX USB Redirection.

Or you can use specialized hardware, such as "Conversions Technology USB Extender Over IP" or "StarTech USB1000IP".